# Help me please, install problems on ACER aspire 5515

Tags: installation, partitioning, acer, aspire

So, I have an ACER Aspire 5515 with Windows 7 Ultimate installed. I have an AMD Athlon(tm) Processor 2650e 1.60 GHz processor. 1 GB RAM, with a 160 GB HDD.

So here's what I did:

I parititioned my hard drive. I have three partitions: a 10 GB hidden partition (for my bios), a 69.5 GB C:/ partition (holds my windows OS), and finally, a 69.5 GB partition that I used to install Ubuntu 12.10. I burned the .iso to a disc, and I formatted the third partition to a ext journaled 4 with the ubuntu install disc, and then I installed Ubuntu on the third partition. Then it took me to a reboot, and rebooted into Windows normally. I have no idea what to do from here, I mean, it seemed like the install process went normal. Any ideas? Help? Instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS needs four partitions: boot, root, home and swap. You should do the partitioning from within the installer.

Follow this guide: [page 1](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/) and [page 2](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/2/)